# Google Drive API download does not allow CORS access to Content-Range response header

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Ran across a problem when accessing byte ranges of files on Google Drive from JavaScript using CORS.

It mostly completely works (props!), but my app would like to see the Content-Range header on the partial response in order to know the total length of the file, but I'm not allowed to get it from the XMLHttpRequest because it isn't listed in the "access-control-expose-headers" header in the response.

I can work around this by using the size from the file's metadata (which I already fetched to get the download URL), but it would be nice to have Content-Range included in access-control-expose-headers, if anybody from the Drive API dev team reads this.

Dump of an example request from Chrome devtools:

**Request URL:** https://doc-0g-38-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/6evfs70tsp1qa1i52rjh8oirj2t88vrd/rve4p35jans7cojv8fbj68flmsm51clj/1380672000000/00355094596910024248/00355094596910024248/0B0-hjEIqYxjYUDF3dDhxNndpd0U?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true

**Request Method:** GET

**Status Code:** 206 Partial Content

**Request Headers**

```
:host:doc-0g-38-docs.googleusercontent.com
:method:GET
:path:/docs/securesc/6evfs70tsp1qa1i52rjh8oirj2t88vrd/rve4p35jans7cojv8fbj68flmsm51clj/1380672000000/00355094596910024248/00355094596910024248/0B0-hjEIqYxjYUDF3dDhxNndpd0U?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
authorization:Bearer ya29.AHES6ZSEzaPW_sYd4BaKNnlD-l73ZDy0XIS-cJlfX_LOT1qR
cache-control:no-cache
origin:http://jbrowse.org:8080
pragma:no-cache
range:bytes=0-65535
referer:http://jbrowse.org:8080/jbrowse/index.html?highlight=&dataRoot=newvolvox
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
h:16653014193614665626
e:download
gd:true
```

**Response Headers**

```
access-control-allow-credentials:false
access-control-allow-headers:Accept, Accept-Language, Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Type, Date, GData-Version, Host, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, Origin, OriginToken, Pragma, Range, Slug, Transfer-Encoding, X-ClientDetails, X-GData-Client, X-GData-Key, X-Goog-AuthUser, X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable, X-Goog-Correlation-Id, X-Goog-Upload-Command, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Disposition, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Length, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type, X-Goog-Upload-Offset, X-Goog-Upload-Protocol, X-Goog-Visitor-Id, X-HTTP-Method-Override, X-JavaScript-User-Agent, X-Origin, X-Referer, X-Upload-Content-Length, X-Upload-Content-Type, X-Use-HTTP-Status-Code-Override, X-YouTube-VVT, X-YouTube-Page-CL, X-YouTube-Page-Timestamp
access-control-allow-methods:GET,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin:*
access-control-expose-headers:Cache-Control, Content-Length, Date, Expires, Server, Transfer-Encoding
alternate-protocol:443:quic
cache-control:private, max-age=0
content-disposition:attachment;filename="volvox-sorted.bam";filename*=UTF-8''volvox-sorted.bam
content-length:65536
content-range:bytes 0-65535/395273
content-type:application/x-gzip
date:Wed, 02 Oct 2013 01:49:09 GMT
expires:Wed, 02 Oct 2013 01:49:09 GMT
server:HTTP Upload Server Built on Sep 30 2013 10:58:35 (1380563915)
status:206 Partial Content
version:HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: This is a known bug with resumable uploads, on our backlog.